# Backbone - loading JSON into collection won't render in the view

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I can't seem to get JSON that is loading into my FriendsCollection to render into FriendListView. I can see that it is loading through the network panel, and I can log the data to the console, but for some reason the fetch command isn't passing the data to the view to be rendered.

I'm using Backbone 1.0.

The code i'm using is available on jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/OHePaki/1/edit?html,js,output

```
// MODELS
var ArtifactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('reset', function(){ artifactView.render() })
    },
    defaults: {
        "text": "Unknown Text",
        "timestamp": "Unknown timestamp"
    }
});
var artifactModel = new ArtifactModel();

// COLLECTIONS
var ArtifactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ArtifactModel,
    url: '/getDigest.json',
    // url: 'http://we365.local/Artifact/GetShareableArtifact?token=b88d2640826bb8593f6edb308ce604f28225f240&artifact_id=2&social_site=tw&log_inside=&go',
    parse: function(data) {
        console.log('running parse');
        return _.map(data.response.content, _.identity);
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.on('reset', function(){ artifactListView.render(); }),
        console.log('running init function for ArtifactCollection');
        this.fetch();
        //this.reset(artifactjson, { parse: true });
        console.log(this.toJSON());
    }
});
var artifactCollection = new ArtifactCollection();


// VIEWS
    var ArtifactView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'single-model',
        render: function(){
            var template = Handlebars.compile($('#stream_getDigest').html());
            this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    var ArtifactListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initalize: function(){
            this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        },
        render: function(){
            this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        },
        addOne: function(artifactModel){
            var artifactView = new ArtifactView({model: artifactModel});
            this.$el.append(artifactView.render().el);
        }
    });


// rendering
var artifactView = new ArtifactView({model: artifactModel});
var artifactListView = new ArtifactListView({collection: artifactCollection});

artifactView.render();
artifactListView.render();

$('#list').html(artifactListView.$el.html());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default jQuery ajax call is asynchronous, the code will keep running without waiting for the `.fetch()` to be finished. In your code the `view` is rendered before the collection is ready so the data for the `view` is empty.

You can pass jQuery ajax option to `fetch` function so you can do the following (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

```
...
initialize: function(){
    this.on('reset', function(){ artifactListView.render(); }),
    console.log('running init function for ArtifactCollection');
    this.fetch({async:false});
    console.log(this.toJSON()); //This will log the loaded collection
}
...
```

Or you can change fetching strategy to take the advantage of asynchronous load:

```
this.fetch().done(function(){
    //Things to do after collection is loaded
});
//this's not good to use in init function
```

Comment: Thank you @BMH, that actually makes a lot of sense. Though I can't believe I haven't found any where that suggested that this could have been the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Is this right? I know that (by default) the code keeps running without waiting for the AJAX response, but I would have thought the `reset` event was fired after the model was updated, rather than immediately after the request was sent. In which case it should work without the `{async:false}` bit.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Yes, it will work with `this.fetch({reset: true});`, but you may need to call `$('#list').html(artifactListView.$el.html());` again to see it takes effect in browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set handlers on the models. Something like this:

```
friendModel.on('change', function() { friendView.render(); });
friendCollection.on('change', function() { friendListView.render(); });
```

Or better yet, put these lines in the constructors for `friendModel` and `friendCollection` (see http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor ).

Comment: i've updated the above code to what I think you are suggesting. I've added initialize methods to the model and the collection, but no such luck.

Comment: I don't know about Collections, but for the Model the event should be `'change'`, not `'reset'`. Also, the way it is now, the view `artifactListView` is not permanently attached to the HTML element. All you've got is the last line, which just reads the contents of the View and copies it to the element. You've got the `tagName` in `ArtifactView`; you should do something similar in `ArtifactListView` instead of using the last line. I can't see any other mistakes... so it looks to me like the two views failed for completely different reasons.

Comment: shouldn't I be getting some sort of error or something to tell me what is going wrong?

I've been trying to get this Json reading for hours, and for some reason it just won't work. I've tried it a few different ways.

Comment: Not all errors produce messages. If it's the two errors I just mentioned, I wouldn't expect to get any error message. Firing a reset event on a model is meaningless, but Backbone allows you to invent your own events, so it doesn't know that reset is a mistake. Creating a view and not attaching it to any particular HTML element is also something that people might sometimes want to do (because it can be added later), so it also doesn't produce an error message. And on second thoughts, maybe setting `tagName` isn't sufficient. Maybe you need to use `setElement`, or `el: $('#list'),`.

Comment: any chance you could take a look at the jsbin i created for this? http://jsbin.com/OHePaki/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: According to http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog you should use `'change'` for models but not collections. Nothing seems to happen when I click the buttons, and I don't see any event handlers for the buttons. So I can't really test it at the moment. Also, are you trying to display both the model and the collection? Or is the model only intended for the `model` field of the collection? And the model has no `url` or `parse` method. (But this probably only matters if you want to display the model.)